# How to handle kind conflicts across apiservice

Tags: kubernetes

I have two apiservice with a Certificate kind: cert-manager.io and certmanager.k8s.io. When I use `kubectl get certificate --all-namespaces` it says no resources found because it appears to be checking certmanager.k8s.io, but my certs are created under cert-manager.io.

I don't need certmanager.k8s.io so I tried deleting it but it won't delete even though it reports it was deleted.

```
kubectl delete apiservice v1alpha1.certmanager.k8s.io  
apiservice.apiregistration.k8s.io "v1alpha1.certmanager.k8s.io" deleted
```

Is there a way to prefer a different apiservice for a specific resource or get the one I don't need deleted?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You might have a CRD somewhere. You can find out .

```sh
$ kubectl get crd --all-namespaces
```

Then if you do, delete it :

```sh
$ kubectl delete crd <crd-name>
```

Sometimes the CRDs have finalizers that will prevent them from being deleted. In which case.

```sh
$ kubectl edit crd <crd-name>
```

Remove the finalizer section in the YAML file:

```yaml
finalizers: 
  - xxxxxx
```

Check that the CRD is not there anymore:

```sh
$ kubectl get crd --all-namespaces
```